what is ()=> mean in javascript for selenium?
In this sentence:
()=>{Object.defineProperties(navigator,{webdriver:{get:()=>false}})}

What does () => mean?
I only know it is a JavaScript and set se page evaluate with selenium
This is for setting page evaluate

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?

It's syntactic sugar for an anonymous function.

()=>{Object.defineProperties(navigator,{webdriver:{get:()=>false}})}

is a so-called arrow function

An arrow function expression is a compact alternative to a traditional function expression, with some semantic differences and deliberate limitations in usage:
Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments, or super, and should not be used as methods.
Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors. Calling them with new throws a TypeError. They also don't have access to the new.target keyword.
Arrow functions cannot use yield within their body and cannot be created as generator functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
The () part is for the parameters and in this case no parameter is given at the declaration. The part inside the {} braces is the function body and this is actually saying that the return value of the function will be
Object.defineProperties(navigator,{webdriver:{get:()=>false}

